# getCallingPid() returning my PID in onBind()

Tags: android

I am just getting started with Android programming, and I have implemented a **very** simple remote service.  I am able to bind to my service from other processes and send simple "ping" and "pong" messages back and forth.  (I am not using AIDL, stubs, etc.  I am just passing `Messages` and using the `what` field.)

I am now investigating permissions, and I've run into a problem.  In my `onBind()` method, `checkCallingPermission()` is always returning `PERMISSION_DENIED`, even though the calling process does have the permission in question (verified by calling `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` in that process).  I suspect that this is happening because `Binder.getCallingUid()` is returning the PID of the server process, rather than the caller.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  `checkCallingPermission()` is supposed to work this way in a service's `onBind()` method, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

onBind() is not processing a transaction that was sent from another process - the Android system is asking your process what to do when someone has bound, and will return the given IBinder to the binding process.

To prevent a process from binding if it does not have a required permission, place the permission in the application manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:permission="my.package.permission.RESTRICT" >          <-- Permission
    <service android:exported="true" android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.package.IAidl" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: This won't work. The system caches binders. Try binding multiple times from different processes. `onBind()` is only called once. If you want to check permissions, you have to implement the permission check within the binder's AIDL method definition.

Answer (score -1):

You must call Binder.getCallingPid() in the method of your binder implementation(extends xxx.Stub)